# How can I extract all the walls from the tile map and add to each one a box collder 2d using algorithm?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure what algorithm and how to use for that.

The trick is to choose the Collider's Center and Size properties so that they are always like 1.25 or 1.5 or 1.75 or 2.00, and never like 1.24687 or 1.25788

The current tile 2d map is type sprite 2d and ui
I added to it a box collider but this is not what I need.

[image: original]

and this is how it should be the result after adding the colliders:

[image: result]

and one of the problems to make it automatic is to make each collider perfectly aligned by center and size.

just for testing I tried this script to see if I can first get to a list all the tiles:
since the map is 8x8 the result i'm getting is 928 items in the list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExtractTilesFromSprite : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite spriteSheet;
    public Vector2Int gridSize = new Vector2Int(16, 16); // Size of each individual tile in pixels

    public List<Sprite> extractedTiles = new List<Sprite>();

    void Start()
    {
        if (spriteSheet == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Sprite sheet reference not set! Please assign the Sprite sheet in the Inspector.");
            return;
        }

        ExtractTiles();
    }

    private void ExtractTiles()
    {
        Texture2D texture = spriteSheet.texture;
        int columns = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteSheet.rect.width / gridSize.x);
        int rows = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteSheet.rect.height / gridSize.y);

        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            {
                int xPos = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteSheet.rect.x + x * gridSize.x);
                int yPos = Mathf.FloorToInt(spriteSheet.rect.y + y * gridSize.y);
                Rect tileRect = new Rect(xPos, yPos, gridSize.x, gridSize.y);

                Sprite tileSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, tileRect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), gridSize.x);
                extractedTiles.Add(tileSprite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this is not what I need, I guess.  I wanted to get each wall/s for example:

[image: example of walls]

I tried this script to add the colliders automatic, but it didn't add them to the right positions and or center:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class AddBoxCollidersToWalls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite wallSprite;

    void Start()
    {
        if (wallSprite == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("WallSprite reference not set! Please assign the WallSprite in the Inspector.");
            return;
        }

        AddCollidersToWallTiles();
    }

    private void AddCollidersToWallTiles()
    {
        Texture2D texture = wallSprite.texture;
        int tileWidth = Mathf.FloorToInt(wallSprite.rect.width / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit);
        int tileHeight = Mathf.FloorToInt(wallSprite.rect.height / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit);

        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y += tileHeight)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x += tileWidth)
            {
                Vector3 colliderCenter = new Vector3((x + tileWidth / 2f) / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, (y + tileHeight / 2f) / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, 0f);
                Vector2 colliderSize = new Vector2(tileWidth / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, tileHeight / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit);

                CreateColliderObject(colliderCenter, colliderSize);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateColliderObject(Vector3 center, Vector2 size)
    {
        GameObject colliderObject = new GameObject("WallTileCollider");
        colliderObject.transform.parent = transform;
        colliderObject.transform.localPosition = center;

        BoxCollider2D collider = colliderObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        collider.size = size;
    }
}
```

the result:

[image: not correct result]